JSONata, error applying expression to arrays of jsons inside multi-level JSON
I used to have an input of the form:
[{
  "id": "abc",
  "week": "2024-01-01",
  "type": "renovation",
  "amount": "0"
}, {
  "id": "def",
  "week": "2024-01-01",
  "type": "new sales",
  "amount": "10"
}, {
  "id": "abc",
  "week": "2024-01-08",
  "type": "renovation",
  "amount": "0"
}]

and the following properly working JSONata expression, responsible for applying a sum on the sales amount, grouping the amount by week:
(
    $jsonata_expression := {
        "sales" : {
            week : {
                "amount" : $sum(amount.$number())
            }
        }
    };
)

However, my tipe of input changed, since the API now sends more than one query result. My current input is something like:
{
  "query_one" : [{
    "id": "abc",
    "week": "2024-01-01",
    "type": "renovation",
    "amount": "0"
  }, {
    "id": "def",
    "week": "2024-01-01",
    "type": "new sales",
    "amount": "10"
  }, {
    "id": "abc",
    "week": "2024-01-08",
    "type": "renovation",
    "amount": "0"
  }],
  "query_two" : [{"key" : "value"}, {"key" : "value"}]
}

And I'm having trouble replicating the JSONata expression to the new form of input.
I've tried doing:
(
    $expected_input := query;
    
    $jsonata_expression := {
        "sales" : {
            $expected_input.week : {
                "amount" : $sum($expected_input.amount.$number())
            }
        }
    };

)

However, this throws an error saying that I cannot group by week, since it's an array.
Key in object structure must evaluate to a string; got: ["2024-01-01","2024-01-08"]
Can someone help me with this scenario? I'm really struggling to understand why it's not working, since the value stored inside of $expected_input is, at least visually speaking, equal to the previous input.

Updates! Found out what I was doing wrong. I forgot to access the query_one object using the object constructor structure.
For those who find this question, the desired result would be achieve by simply doing:
(    
$jsonata_expression := query_one{
    "sales" : {
        week : {
            "amount" : $sum(amount.$number())
        }
    }
};

)
